# localhost is currently unable to handle this request - Moodle WAMP

Tags: php, moodle

A frequent moodle localhost, caused an unexpected error

```
"This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
null"
```

None of the links/courses/Turn Editing on is working!

I tried to uncomment module_rewrite @ http.conf, restarted my server, but none of them worked.

Comment: most probably you have fatal error in your code. check in apache error log.

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21516022/8096817

Comment: [Tue Dec 18 18:02:25.030519 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7940:tid 640] AH00094: Command line: 'F:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.27\\bin\\httpd.exe -d F:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27'
[Tue Dec 18 18:02:25.035525 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7940:tid 640] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1096
[Tue Dec 18 18:02:25.857178 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1096:tid 704] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: @Shanteshwar Inde - Above is the code taken from apache error log file

Answer (score -1):

Your server may have error reporting turned off. Add this code to the top of the page to see what is causing the error.

```
<?php error_reporting(-1); ?>
<?php ini_set('display_errors', true); ?>
```

Comment: I have not one or three files. Its completely a moodle package